# Passing commands in Inno Setup exec function into pgsql database

Tags: postgresql, inno-setup

I'm running the following code trying to create users in my PostgreSQL database from a file which my Inno Setup script reads. Unfortunately the only commands which execute are the `SET PGPPASSWORD` and `-U postgres elt` commands which connect me to the database.  The other commands which I need to run inside the database are ignored and I cannot seem to find a way to input them into the database. Is there characters I can use to input the commands into the PostgreSQL database?

```pascal
ExecAsOriginalUser('cmd.exe', '/k ' +'"SET PGPASSWORD=postgres&"' + 
    InstallPath+ '\psql -U postgres elt -c '+ 'CREATE USER ' 
    + Users[UserCount - 1] + ' WITH PASSWORD ' + '''' 
    + Password + '''' + '& ' + '\g', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilIdle, ResultCode);
```

Command Line Output:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "-c" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "CREATE" ignored
"": warning: extra command-line argument "USER" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "postgres" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "WITH" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "PASSWORD" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "'postgres'\g" ignorepsql 
(9.5.3) WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from    
Windows code page 
(1252) 8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference page    
"Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.
db=#
```

Comment: Use `Log('/k ' +'"SET PGPASSWORD=postgres&"' + 
InstallPath+ '\psql -U postgres elt -c '+ 'CREATE USER ' 
+ Users[UserCount - 1] + ' WITH PASSWORD ' + '''' 
+ Password + '''' + '& ' + '\g')` and show us the **exact** result.

Comment: What does the `'& ' + '\g'` mean?

Comment: What's the `InstallPath`? Does it contain spaces?

Comment: Here is the debug output, the \g compiles the commands once their entered into postgres, eg. to perform an operation like DROP USER Martin, I'd need to type in the command with a \g at the end, otherwise the database will not perform it.  Install Path contains pgsql's bin directory and there are no spaces in it "C:\files\pgsql\bin"

Comment: /k "SET PGPASSWORD=postgres&"C:\eltfiles\pgsql\bin\psql -U postgres elt -c CREATE USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres'& \g

Comment: And why the `&` before the `\g`?

Comment: & specifies that command line should run the command after running the previous one.  for example if I wanted to change directories and then run a bat file I could write cd C:\batdir& service.bat.  For the \g though I realized it was unecessary as all you need to do is append the \g to make the command run and have removed it. Still having troubles getting everything after -c to run within the postgres db

Comment: So if you remove the `&` and type `cmd .exe /k "SET PGPASSWORD=postgres&"C:\eltfiles\pgsql\bin\psql -U postgres elt -c CREATE USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres' \g ` on command-line, does it work?

Comment: psql: warning: extra command-line argument "-c" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "CREATE" ignored
"": warning: extra command-line argument "USER" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "postgres" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "WITH" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "PASSWORD" ignored
"": extra command-line argument "'postgres'\g" ignorepsql (9.5.3) WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from    Windows code page (1252) 8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.
db=#

Comment: Sorry for the format, but these are the errors I get when attempting to use the db I'll try to make it prettier in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to wrap the SQL to double quotes:

```
ExecAsOriginalUser('cmd.exe',
    '/c SET PGPASSWORD=postgres& '
    + InstallPath + '\psql -U postgres elt -c "CREATE USER ' 
    + Users[UserCount - 1] + ' WITH PASSWORD ''' + Password + '''"',
    '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilIdle, ResultCode);
```

First verify it by running this on a command-line:

```
cmd.exe /c SET PGPASSWORD=postgres& C:\eltfiles\pgsql\bin\psql -U postgres elt -c "CREATE USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres'"
```

Comment: This was partly right, however after returning to it on my own, I ficured out that my usage of the -c command was incorrect.  To make this command work you need to type \psql -U user -c "psql synax" database;  By typing \psql -U postgres elt -c... I made the command stop after postgres elt because it assumed that all I wanted to do was log into the database with the username postgres.

Comment: Can you edit the correct syntax into my answer? Or post your own.